# How to GRANT permissions to users in a stored procedure SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I want to grant exec permission to a user. This code returns no errors but then when I see the user properties I don't see the permission granted.

```
GRANT EXECUTE TO @USERNAME
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GRANT` statement needs both an object and a principal.  You only have a principal.

What do you want to allow the user to do - execute a single Stored Procedure or all stored procedures?   The object would define that. For example if your stored procedure was named `MySchema.MyProc` then you would apply the permissions like:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON MySchema.MyProc TO MyUser
```

To allow the user to execute any stored procedure in the `MySchema` schema then it becomes:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::MySchema TO MyUser
```

Comment: In fact, no, the `GRANT` statement doesn't need to have an explicit securable specified. If a securable isn't specified, the permission is applied to any securable within that scope (i.e. database for database-scoped permissions, server for server-scoped permissions).

Answer (score 0):

While testing your scenario, I also don't see the the permission reflected in the SSMS at the user level. However, here are three ways in which I *can* see the permission (I called my user foo because I pity the foo):

1. Impersonating the user and looking at database permissions:

```
execute as user = 'foo';
select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');
go
revert
go
```

2. Interrogating the permissions table directly:

```
select *
from sys.database_permissions
where grantee_principal_id = user_id('foo');
```

Note - the way in which you're granting permissions grants it to anything (both now and the future) which can have that permission applied. That is, all stored procedures, functions, etc in the database. If that's not what you meant to do (i.e. you only meant to grant permission to one stored procedure), then you need to specify it in the `GRANT` statement. I only mention this because what you're doing technically works but in my experience is more the exception than the rule.

Answer (score -2):

you need to grant permissions in the database where stored procedure were created, in sql server this option is located in db login --> right click --> new